# Unable to connect PHP and interbase

Tags: php, interbase

I have a system that need to be run on interbase. When doing the setup, i get this error when trying to start my apache.

**Error message:**

> PHP startup: interbase: Unable to initialize module
>  Module
>   compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC6
>  PHP compiled with build
>   ID=API20090626,TS,VC9
>  These options need to match

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "interbase" module were build with different complier version. You need to find VC9 version to load it with your current PHP release. I suggest to use standard [***ODBC** driver*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) if all attempts fail.

You may find more information on differently compiled PHP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793751/whats-the-difference-between-the-many-versions-of-php).

Comment: how to get the VC9 version for the interbase?